# How to make codes in this flutter stopwatch?

Tags: flutter, calculator, stopwatch

I am a beginner of flutter!
Making a 'STUDY TIME STOPWATCH', i want to display a caluation.

ex) 'Now you are a (1.245)^(10-t) grade'       <= (1.245)^(10-t) is my personal formula

[t= (hour) + (minute/60) + (second/3600)]

But i cannot do this.... how to resolve this problem??

Comment: can you define exactly what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, as I understand is you want to convert your formulae to flutter code? if so do the following.

```
var x=10-t;
var power=pow(1.245,x);    // pow is dart function to calculate power]
```

and what you want to do with this part?
[t= (hour) + (minute/60) + (second/3600)]